# Delay Self Assessment Return

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, capital-gains-tax, savings

**I am a international student holding a residence visa.**

A month ago, I began my degree program, and I have some income from a **non-ISA** savings account. I recently noticed that the deadline for filing my self-assessment return has already passed.

1. Is it necessary for me to file a self-assessment return?
2. What should I do if I missed the deadline for creating an HMRC account?

I appreciate your assistance in advance.

Comment: What tax year does this relate to? Have HMRC explicitly told you that you need to file a self-assessment return?

Answer (score 4):

The deadline for submitting a UK self-assesment tax return is 31st January - but bear in mind that this is for the previous tax year. So if you need to submit a self-assessment for 2022-23, you have until 31st January 2024.

Also bear in mind that if your only source of income is interest on a savings account, it's unlikely that you need to submit a self-assessment. [According to HMRC](https://www.gov.uk/apply-tax-free-interest-on-savings), you do not have to pay tax on savings interest until your total earnings from all sources exceed your [personal allowance](https://www.gov.uk/income-tax-rates) (currently £12570).

Of course, if you are getting more than 12 grand in interest from your savings, then you can almost certainly afford to pay for tax advice from someone who knows what they're talking about!